# How to Use LoginGdi+ theme

Tags: vb.net

Guys would you please tell me how to use this theme in my project ?
I like this theme & I want to know how to use it
the theme link  http://xertzproductions.weebly.com/login-gdi-theme.html
I tried but I failed !
thanks in advance

Comment: What did you try? How did you fail? Flagged to be closed as unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Based on the docs, you just need to add a new class to your project and paste de code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the code from the pastebin and paste it inside of the main forms code. Run the application and look inside of the toolbox.

Comment: I really thank you Guys ,my problem is solved...
I repaired my Visual Studio version and it is  working right now.